# ffmpeg: convert an existing audio stream as an additional audio stream (keeping untouched original as well)

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, conversion

I have a video with 1 video stream, 2 audio streams (TrueHD 7.1 and E-AC3 5.1), a bunch of PGS subtitles and chapters.

I want to copy the video, convert the 7.1 audio into AAC, copy over the original 7.1 and 5.1 streams (so 3 audio streams), keep only French and English subtitles and all the metadata.

After a few trials, this command seems to do exactly that:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:m:language:eng -map 0:m:language:fre -c copy -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 512k output.mkv
```

Stream mapping:

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (truehd (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy) # truehd 7.1
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:3 (copy) # e-ac3 5.1
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:4 (copy) # (English subtitles)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:5 (copy) # (French subtitles)
```

Now the question is... if I wanted to get rid of the e-ac3, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 512k -map 0:a:0 -c:a:1 copy -map 0:s:0 -c:s:0 copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -map 0:s:1 -c:s:1 copy -metadata:s:s:1 language=fre output.mkv

```
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (truehd (native) -> aac (native))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy) # truehd 7.1
Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy) # (English subtitles)
Stream #0:6 -> #0:4 (copy) # (French subtitles)
```

If I've done this correctly it should only copy or encode what you asked for and nothing else..

```
-canvas_size 1920x804 (WidthxHeight of video.. Is needed to copy DVD & Blu-ray picture based subtitles over..)
```

And on a side note:

```
-map 0:m:language:eng (Missing Index on which stream metadata should be changed)
-map 0:m:language:fre (Missing Index on which stream metadata should be changed)
-c copy (This will copy all streams over regardless of mapping..)
```